# Кавычки в мысленной речи, растянутой на несколько абзацев: выделять кавычками каждый абзац или только начало и конец мыслей?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки, прямая-речь, авторская-пунктуация, абзац

Скажите, как в книге оформить мысли персонажа, если они растянуты на несколько абзацев? Стягивать в один абзац не вариант. Нужно ли закавычивать каждый абзац отдельно или следует всего двумя кавычками показать границу мыслей? Есть примеры такие в литературе? Вот, скажем, в таком случае как оформить?

*Она беззастенчиво прошлась по тротуару и обернулась.*

*"Чего она на меня так смотрит? Съесть, что ли, хочет?..(")*

*(")Хотя нет, совсем на неё непохоже(").*

*(")А вдруг...(")*

*(")Да нет, что это я, старый совсем стал. Кому я нужен? Вот и ей не нужен. Ну её(").*

*(")Но всё-таки. А вдруг..."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Громоздить кавычки не вариант, потому что тогда это будет выглядеть как диалог (именно так выглядят диалоги в английском языке: каждая реплика в кавычках и с нового абзаца. У них не используются тире в начале реплик). Поэтому, конечно, две кавычки -- и всё.
А можно и вовсе не использовать кавычки. Это называется "несобственно-прямая речь" -- когда мысли персонажа не выделяются пунктуационно, но выделяются лексически.

Answer (score 1):

**Несобственно-прямая речь** оформляется немного по-другому. Там повествование ведется от лица автора, но при этом передаются мысли и чувства героя. Также используется местоимение "он", а не "я, меня". Желательно в начале абзаца использовать какую-нибудь фразу, обозначающую действие.

В качестве варианта:

*Он пошел дальше, чувствуя на себе ее взгляд. Чего она **на него** так смотрит? Съесть, что ли, хочет?.. Хотя нет, совсем на неё непохоже. А вдруг... Да нет, что это **он**, старый совсем стал. Кому он нужен? Вот и ей не нужен. Ну её. Но всё-таки. А вдруг...*

Comment: Необязательно, что сохраняется третье лицо. Вот, к примеру, фрагмент из повести Владимира Михайлова, 1983 год: https://i.imgur.com/jQvlkAe.png Это не единичный случай, просто то, что вспомнил навскидку. (А повесть, "Стебелёк и два листика", рекомендую к прочтению, даже если научная фантастика вам не по душе. Она про человека, а фантастика -- просто антураж, декорация.)

Comment: Спасибо, обязательно посмотрю на вашу повесть...  Что касается оформления несобственно-прямой речи, то это будет уже не классический и ненормированный вариант. В приведенном отрывке весь текст идет сплошным потоком, там все перемешано. Вероятно, такой у автора стиль.  Какой стиль в данном случае, мы не знаем, но можно предположить, что  традиционный, в рамках правил.