# Абзацное членение выборочных мысленных фраз: как оформить с кавычками, чтобы не смахивало на диалог?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки, оформление-текста, цитирование, абзац

Как оформить фразы второстепенного персонажа, если герой выборочно вспоминает их, а в тексте оригинала они приведены каждая с абзаца? Абзацное деление важно сохранить (!), иначе оформил бы, скажем, в один абзац через запятую. К слову, [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/470923/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0) поднималась схожая тема, и в ответе там указали, что, если подряд будут идти несколько абзацев прямой речи, каждый из которых закавычен, это может восприниматься как диалог. Не нужно ли тогда куда-нибудь к каждой фразе пристыковать многоточие, чтобы показать, что реплики не связаны, они вырваны из контекста, произнесены в разное время и не составляют диалог? Что посоветуете? Знаете ли примеры оформления схожих случаев в литературе?

*Его слова эхом отдавались в голове.*

*"Или иди, или лежи. Третьего не дано".*

*"С меня хватит. Дай гранату и заройся в землю поглубже".*

*"Я тебе не папочка, но по башке настучать могу".*

*"Всего хорошего, ублюдки!"*

*"Решай сам. Но могу посоветовать развернуться и дать дёру, пока всех не положили".*

*Так захотелось ещё хоть раз услышать от него какую-нибудь колкость...*

**ДОПОЛНЕНО**

Ответ "Граммы.ру", честно говоря, меня не устраивает, поскольку в их  варианте оформления все цитаты смешиваются в одно предложение.

> Если персонаж в сцене/эпизоде один, можно оформить так, как в оригинале. Вариант: "Или иди, или лежи. Третьего не дано... С меня хватит. Дай гранату и заройся в землю поглубже... Я тебе не папочка, но по башке настучать могу... Всего хорошего, ублюдки!.. Решай сам. Но могу посоветовать развернуться и дать дёру, пока всех не положили..."

"Грамота.ру" тоже почему-то отвергает необходимость сохранения абзацного членения (см. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=309657)).

> Если мы правильно поняли ситуацию, то возможно такое оформление.
> Его слова эхом отдавались в голове: "Или иди, или лежи. Третьего не дано"; "С меня хватит. Дай гранату и заройся в землю поглубже"; "Я тебе не папочка, но по башке настучать могу"; "Всего хорошего, ублюдки!"; "Решай сам. Но могу посоветовать развернуться и дать дёру, пока всех не положили". Так захотелось ещё хоть раз услышать от него какую-нибудь колкость...
> Написание каждой фразы с абзацного отступа нам кажется неудачным решением.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть как пунктуационные, так и типографские решения.

1. Сохранить абзацное членение, но оформить отрывок в общие кавычки.
2. Убрать кавычки, но отрывок сделать иной гарнитурой шрифта, либо курсивом.
3. Не менять сам отрывок, но перед и после него сделать увеличенные интервалы.

Вариант с многоточием не поддерживаю, так как нет объективных причин для его постановки: никого не перебили, ни о чём не умолчали, никакую последовательность не подразумевали. А напускное глубокомыслие, которое якобы добавляется при помощи многоточия, — это вообще далеко от литературы.

Но если бы я сам для себя решал, как оформить отрывок, то сделал бы его одним абзацем и с множеством цитат, заключённых в кавычки. Этот вариант оформления точно соответствует задаче: абзац как единая мысль, кавычки указывают на цитирование, а прерывистость кавычек показывает, что мысль не сквозная, а раздробленная.

**Дополнение:**

У пунктуации невелик инструментарий. Из того, что не обсудили, остались только скобки. В переводах Стивена Кинга порой ментальную речь вставляют в скобки, как бы демонстрируя, что она где-то за кадром происходящего. А всё остальное (тире, запятые. кавычки, многоточия) мы уже обсудили. Могу также предложить авторский знак двоеточие (..). Например, использовался в "Чаше Афродиты" Н.Никонова. Имеет отличное от многоточия значение, которое может быть любым, от пауз до разрыва цитат. Кстати, можете также использовать знак разрыва цитаты внутри целостного абзаца кавычек.

Comment: Третий глаз, я с вами согласен, что лучше всего — в 1 абзаце, каждая фраза в своих кавычках и через запятую (кстати, "Грамота.ру" поставила не запятые, а точки с запятой в своём варианте — интересно, почему).  Но мне важны ещё варианты, особенно, если такие есть в литературе. Другой шрифт или интервалы — возможно, но чисто теоретически есть ли ещё ПУНКТУАЦИОННЫЕ решения?..

Comment: @ShiKomarishe я дополнил ответ

Answer (score 1):

Его слова эхом отдавались в голове:

— Или иди, или лежи. Третьего не дано...

— С меня хватит. Дай гранату и заройся в землю поглубже...

— Я тебе не папочка, но по башке настучать могу...

— Всего хорошего, ублюдки!..

— Решай сам. Но могу посоветовать развернуться и дать дёру, пока всех не положили...

Так захотелось ещё хоть раз услышать от него какую-нибудь колкость!

---

(Соглашаясь с «Грамота.ру» в оценке решения, всё же иду до конца: поддержу идею с многоточием, избавлю текст от кавычек — очевидно, что лишь о припоминаемых фразах идёт речь, — и введу характерные для оформления «реплик» тире.)

---

Его слова эхом отдавались в голове:

«*Или иди, или лежи. Третьего не дано.*

*С меня хватит. Дай гранату и заройся в землю поглубже.*

*Я тебе не папочка, но по башке настучать могу*.

*Всего хорошего, ублюдки!*

*Решай сам. Но могу посоветовать развернуться и дать дёру, пока всех не положили*».

Так захотелось ещё хоть раз услышать от него какую-нибудь колкость!

---

Блок будет плотнее — не как в этом редакторе, и это пойдёт ему на пользу.

---

Comment: shampar, но ведь в таком варианте это превращается в самый настоящий диалог: тире у каждой реплики просто кричат об этом... К тому же это ведь мысленные цитаты, а для них в любом случае нужны кавычки. Так что нет, с тире не пойдёт, это как раз то, чего надо избежать.

Comment: Вы не учитываете вступительную часть. Там всё однозначно сказано о «его» словах.

Comment: Вот потому и задаю этот вопрос. Допустимо ли оставить так, как есть (в вопросе), или же есть другие способы, литературные примеры на такой подобный случай?..

Comment: Добавлю вариант.

Comment: Что ж, при закавычивании всех этих абзацных фраз в одни кавычки действительно вообще не воспринимается, как диалог. Но в то же время кажется, что это один связанный мысленный текст, поделённый на абзацы... В любом случае этот вариант гораздо лучше, чем с тире.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что перед цитированием надо каким-то образом обозначить в повествовании, что вспомненные отрывки были озвучены не в один период времени, не в одном диалоге.
Например, *вспомнились слова, сказанные в разное время*, или *вспомнилось услышанное в разное время*.

И вот тогда читателю будет совершенно понятно, что перед ним никакой не диалог, а ***разновременное*** цитирование. И вот тогда можно не ставить двоеточие, но — цитировать с абзаца (с кавычками, или *курсивом*, или

```
              выделением фона).
```

**В качестве варианта** (курсив можно заменить на предложения в кавычках)

Слова его вспоминались вразброс и эхом отдавались в голове.

*Или иди, или лежи. Третьего не дано.*
<...>
*Решай сам. Но могу посоветовать развернуться и дать дёру, пока всех не положили.*

Так захотелось ещё хоть раз услышать от него какую-нибудь колкость...

P. S. Вот [**здесь**](https://slovodel.com/22969813-sekret_semeinogo_schast_ya) есть фоновое оформление цитат (без двоеточия).